# Build component to connect Java Application to device printer

Tags: java, printing, communication, thermal-printer, network-printers

Some  idea about how can I connect a Java Application to a printer device (and thermal printers too ) and print the information that I want?
My idea is connect from LPT, COM and TCP.

If you have links to some manual it would be appreciate I do not find so much clear information about this and I am so interested in that.

Thanks.

PD: Sorry for my english skills.

Comment: What do you need to print? Is it for sale tickets and things like that?

Comment: Yes, things like that tickets for products, sell tickets,,...